# Why am I not getting an error when I enter a city name which is non-existent?

Tags: java, android, json, try-catch, openweathermap

I'm trying to create a weather app which retrieves the weather information of the entered city name from a weather API using JSON Objects.
My question is, how come if I enter a random city name, it still manages to show details from non-existent JSON objects?
It seems that my try and catch clauses have no effect? Like there is never an error.
If you enter the correct city name like London, then it will give you the accurate information. But if you enter a random city name like "fhjasfhjlas"(clearly not a city), it still gives info for that particular city. Shouldn't it give me an error as it failed to find that particular URL? And from where is the information being displayed coming from when those attributes with that name do not exist.

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout weatherLayout;
RelativeLayout beginLayout;

EditText cityName;
DownloadTask task;
TextView temperatureTV;
TextView descriptionTV;
TextView cityTV;
TextView maxtempTV;
TextView mintempTV;
TextView pressureTV;
TextView windTV;
TextView humidityTV;
TextView textView;
TextView main;
Button getWeatherButton;
ImageView weatherImage;


public void getWeather(View view)   {

    String city = cityName.getText().toString();
    cityTV.setText(city);

    try {
        String encodedCityName = URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8");

        String cityURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCityName + "&appid=226e3e9286a8df16f6a3e4d032f58159";
        try {
            task.execute(cityURL);
        }
         catch (Exception e)   {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather, check city name and Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather, check city name and Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    getWeatherButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    cityName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    weatherLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String>  {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";

        URL url;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1)  {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather, check city name and Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");
            String mainInfo = jsonObject.getString("main");
            String windInfo = jsonObject.getString("wind");

            JSONArray weatherJsonArray = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

            for (int i = 0; i < weatherJsonArray.length(); i++)    {

                JSONObject weatherJsonArrayJSONObject = weatherJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                main.setText(weatherJsonArrayJSONObject.getString("main"));

                descriptionTV.setText(weatherJsonArrayJSONObject.getString("description"));
            }

            JSONObject mainInfoObject = new JSONObject(mainInfo);

                Double kelvin = Double.parseDouble(mainInfoObject.getString("temp"));
                Double celcius = kelvin - 273.15;
                Double floorOfKelvin = Math.floor(celcius);
                String stringCelcius = floorOfKelvin.toString();
                temperatureTV.setText(stringCelcius + "°C");

                pressureTV.setText(mainInfoObject.getString("pressure") + "Pa");

                humidityTV.setText(mainInfoObject.getString("humidity") + " %");

                Double mintTempKelvin = Double.parseDouble(mainInfoObject.getString("temp_min"));
                Double minTempcecius = mintTempKelvin - 273.15;
                Double floorOfMinTempKelvin = Math.floor(minTempcecius);
                String stringMinTemp = floorOfMinTempKelvin.toString();

                mintempTV.setText(stringMinTemp + "°C");

                Double maxtTempKelvin = Double.parseDouble(mainInfoObject.getString("temp_max"));
                Double maxTempcecius = maxtTempKelvin - 273.15;
                Double floorOfMaxTempKelvin = Math.floor(maxTempcecius);
                String stringMaxTemp = floorOfMaxTempKelvin.toString();

                maxtempTV.setText(stringMaxTemp + "°C");




            JSONObject windInfoObject = new JSONObject(windInfo);

                windTV.setText(windInfoObject.getString("speed") + " M/h");

        } catch (JSONException e) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather, there was am error creating the JSON Object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cityName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cityName);

    task = new DownloadTask();

    temperatureTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    descriptionTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
    cityTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city);
    maxtempTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maxtempValue);
    mintempTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mintempValue);
    pressureTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pressureValue);
    windTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.windValue);
    humidityTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.humidityValue);
    main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main);

    weatherLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.weatherData);
    beginLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.beginLayout);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    getWeatherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getWeather);
}
}
```

And here is my content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.iboundiaye.jsondemo.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:background="@drawable/weathernew"
android:visibility="visible"
android:id="@+id/beginLayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter City Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cityName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Weather"
    android:id="@+id/getWeather"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cityName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="getWeather" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/weatherData"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="95°"
        android:id="@+id/temperature"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Main"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_below="@+id/temperature"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Description"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="city"
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Humidity"
        android:id="@+id/humidity"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Wind"
        android:id="@+id/wind"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/humidity"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Pressure"
        android:id="@+id/pressure"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/wind"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Min temp"
        android:id="@+id/mintemp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pressure"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Max temp"
        android:id="@+id/maxtemp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mintemp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/maxtempValue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maxtemp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/maxtemp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mintempValue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/mintempValue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maxtemp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pressureValue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/pressureValue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maxtemp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/windValue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/windValue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maxtemp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/humidityValue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/humidityValue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maxtemp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is the value is the same when you enter not exists cities? so maybe this is the default in the api...

Comment: No, its not default output, that they are showing.

Answer (score 1):

In their API response, they have written to query using cityID to ensure that you get unambiguous results.

Here is the link: http://openweathermap.org/current#name. Use that to accurate results.

Also, see here: http://openweathermap.org/find when you enter a city name (even random), it is able to find a city and it has been mentioned that this search is very flexible. So, there are higher chances of finding a city, even if you put some random text.

Comment: Thanks man, we seem to be on to something!
So how do you suggest I do this, the list containing the id's of the different cities is on a file that I have to download.
So I have to find the corresponding id for the city name entered while looking through this file using the same method as before (Finding particular strings in the JSON objets), then use that id and place it in the URL?
If so, how do I access the downloaded file containing the city names and ID's?